# react-native-geocoding going into error in production for android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geocoding

I am using react-native-geocoding for reverse geo coding.

It was working fine in local and test.

But when i switch to production in android i am getting the error below.

```
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoding';
 Geocoder.init('key');
Geocoder.from(‘data’)
        .then((response) => {
      
        })
        .catch(error => {
    
        });
```

Response
{"code":2,"message":"Error while fetching. Check your network.","origin":{}}

is there any configuration i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoding';
```

check your library may be you installed react-native-geocoder and you import the wrong library or you used the wrong event check the documentation of react-native-geocoder.

check this one:

```
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoder';
```